# Bootstrap Image Grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a responsive image grid as in the picture below:
[image]

How do I use bootstrap columns and rows to achieve this?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 sm-12"
<img class="img-thumbnail" scr=".......">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 sm-12"
<img class="img-thumbnail" scr=".......">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 sm-12"
<img class="img-thumbnail" scr=".......">
</div>
........
...........
.................
.....................
</div>
```

I place all the columns inside a single row so that the column elements wrap themselves but this does not happen.
When I implement the code above, due to "height: auto" some images are long and this creates void white space between images of different rows.
I get something like this as a result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

depending on you requirement, you need to replace `col-3` with `col-sm-3` or `col-md-3`, etc:

```css
img
{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" alt="Lights" >
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" alt="Lights" >
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/wedding.jpg"alt="Lights" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="Lights" >
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="Lights" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="Lights" >
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" alt="Lights" >
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/wedding.jpg"alt="Lights" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" alt="Lights" >
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="Lights" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with card columns. JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kax38Lg5/8/):

```
<div class="container-fluid pt-3">
<div class="card-columns">
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 200px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 500px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 300px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 400px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 400px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 300px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 500px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 200px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 200px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 500px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 300px;"/>
</div>
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%; height: 400px;"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with just bootstrap.
Look for the masonry ( https://masonry.desandro.com/ ) or isotope ( https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ ) plugin for bootstrap.